# Console application vs dll vs Windows application etc

Tags: c++

When I start a new project in Visual Studio, I have a few options to choose from: Windows application, console application, dll, static library. What exactly are the differences and when should I use which?
(Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to C++.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Windows application will start the application as a Windows Window, a console application is confined to the console/terminal. If you're new to C++ you don't really need to learn about DLLs and static libraries just yet. You should probably just stick to the console application for now.

Comment: Why do you curmudgeons want to restrict these types of questions? It is valid because Visual Studio gives you so many options even if to only print Hello World. Imagine describing colour to a blind man, to him colour is complicated, to anyone with eyes, colour is an obvious thing - so too is this, but let's not stop the blind from learning!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Console application.
  Create an executable program ([.exe] file) with console subsystem. This means that each running program instance will be outfitted with an associated console window. Either an existing one or a new one.
- Windows application.
  Create an executable program with either console or GUI subsystem. GUI subsystem is the default. The difference from console subsystem is (only) that a console window is not automatically created when the program is run.
- Static library.
  This is a kind of library where the code that's used by some application, gets copied into that application's executable file.
- DLL.
  Dynamically linked library. This is a kind of library whose code isn't copied into each using executable file. Instead the code is dynamically placed into each running instance's memory. Due to this feature a single DLL file can be shared between many programs. Another feature is that code in a DLL can be really private and use its own runtime library.

Console versus GUI subsystem can be very easily changed in the project properties, after the project has been created.

Static library versus DLL isn't really switchable after creation.

Do note that with GUI subsystem Microsoft's linker (unlike e.g. the GCC toolchain linker) will by default not accept a standard `main`. To force it to accept the standard, specify **entry point** `mainCRTStartup` in the linker settings. When you use the standard project templates this must be done after project creation.

Also, if you want standard behavior then it's a good idea to turn off **precompiled headers** in the project creation wizard. Can be turned off also after project creation. But it's easiest and least hassle to do it already at creation.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified a lot :)!

Answer (score 2):

- A Windows application project creates an application with a graphical user interface and OS message handling.
- A console-application is completely text-based and executed in a console window. It's the most simple form of application and used in many tutorials to explain basic language features.
- Static libraries and DLLs can not be executed on their own. But they provide functionality which can be used by other programs. The difference between static libraries and DLLs is that when a program used them, the static library is copied into the executable file while a DLL file is a separate file.

Comment: A console-application is *not* completely text-based. All GUI or graphics libraries or framework I've ever tried were used by what the Visual Studio IDE would call "console applications". It just *defaults* to text-only I/O.

Answer (score 0):

A console application is something that will run in a console window (CMD) just for quick simple applications.
A windows application will be a GUI based application using the "windows.h" header file. It also comes with a window template.
A dll static library is used to create a DLL. Read [What is a DLL from the Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065)